# My turtles just won't lay eggs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have two turtles in minecraft. I give them both seagrass, then they bread and I get xp, but they just don't lay eggs! By the way, after they've breading, I can give one endless amount of seagrass and the other not at all. When I let them go to their home beach, he only swims in circles. What's the problem? Could it be a minecraft bug?

Comment: Are you sure they're making it to their home beaches?  sometimes people destroy them, or build up around them and make the home beach inaccessible....

Answer (score 0):

The turtles have to be where they spawned, unrelated to the question the baby turtles when they grow up they can also only lay eggs where they spawned/hatched

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a [known Bedrock Edition bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-59043) that causes turtles to swim in circles and not lay eggs after breeding. Unfortunately, if this is the issue, there's not much of a way around it without using cheats; it is, however, being fixed in 1.16.

For Java Edition players, there are a couple other possibilities.

According to https://minecraft.wiki/w/Turtle#Breeding:

> Feeding two turtles seagrass causes them to enter love mode, causing one of the turtles to have eggs in its inventory and appear a bit bigger (about .2 of a block) than normal turtles. The pregnant turtle then travels back to its home beach, which is where it first spawned. Upon arrival, it seeks a nearby sand block on which to lay its eggs. The turtle digs vigorously for several seconds a few times - with pauses, on top of the sand, and then lays 1–4 turtle eggs. The pregnant turtle can breed again immediately after laying the eggs while the other turtle can mate immediately after mating.

So in short, turtles can only lay eggs where they originally hatched/spawned. Turtles won't lay eggs when kept in an enclosure unless it happens to be on their home beach. It sounds like you've already ensured they have a clear path to their home beach, but also make sure the beach has plenty of sand blocks to lay eggs on.

Also remember that zombies and drowned will seek out turtle eggs and try to stomp on them. It is possible that the turtle laid its eggs but they got destroyed before hatching.

Note that turtles grow slightly larger in size when they're pregnant; try comparing the turtle you believe to be carrying an egg to another one to confirm the breeding actually worked properly.